# Formal Languages - Matching this regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I'm trying to write a regular expression over the alphabet {0,1,2} for the language in which every 1 is preceded by 0. For example 2200201010, 01022020102012 are strings of the language.

I've tried with this:

```
(0+2)*(01)*(0+2)*(01)*(0+2)*
```

, where '+' means {0,2,00,02,20,22,.....}.
Is this reg-exp correct?
Thank you

Comment: Why not? The '*' include zero, one or more

Comment: Right. But it doesn't include 01201201.

Comment: Right. Should I put that expression in another ( ... ) * ?

Comment: Something of this sort.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @D.W. you are right, but your concept to ask friends, teacher could be done for all the questions. I've asked here because I could not ask them, and needed  as soon as possible. And I check for cs section here ..

Comment: @Alberto, I understand.  You may ignore the part about asking friends or a teacher, if that helps.  The relevant part is that "please check whether my answer is correct" questions tend not to be a good fit for our site's format.  Part of our goal is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will likely be useful to others as well in the future, and "please check my answer" is unlikely to be useful to anyone else in the future.  Just trying to help you understand which types of questions are most likely to work well on this particular site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(01+2+0)*` this may work because the string will contain any combination of given inputs and a 1 will always be preceded by a 0.

Comment: This should be best solution. Thanks :)